# Fixing warning message: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

'''`> seg.df.cut$email <- factor (ifelse(seg.df$email < median (seg.df$email), 1, 2))`'''
Warning message:
In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
all of the other variables I'm converting are working just fine, moving further
along if I ignore this and try poLCA, I receive this follow up message
'''`> seg.f<-with(seg.df.cut,cbind(age,credit.score,email,distance.to.store,online.visits,online.trans,online.spend,store.trans,store.spend)~1)`'''
'''`> seg.LCA4<-poLCA(seg.f,data=seg.df.cut,nclass=4)`'''
Error in runif(R * K.j[j]) : invalid arguments
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
7: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
8: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
9: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
10: In cbind(1, exb) :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

```
    my dataset looks like this
```

''' `>str(seg.df)`'''

```
    'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  9 variables:
     $ age              : num  22.9 28 35.9 30.5 38.7 ...
     $ credit.score     : num  631 749 733 830 734 ...
     $ email            : chr  "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" ...
     $ distance.to.store: num  2.58 48.18 1.29 5.25 25.04 ...
     $ online.visits    : int  20 121 39 1 35 1 1 48 0 14 ...
     $ online.trans     : int  3 39 14 0 11 1 1 13 0 6 ...
     $ online.spend     : num  58.4 756.9 250.3 0 204.7 ...
     $ store.trans      : int  4 0 0 2 0 0 2 4 0 3 ...
     $ store.spend      : num  140.3 0 0 95.9 0 ...
```

Comment: `median(seg.df$email)` - you can't take a `median()` of a categorical variable.

Comment: What is the median value of `c("yes", "yes", "no")`?  It simply doesn't make sense. Maybe you want to make it into a numeric value where `"yes"` is 1 and `"no"` is 0. If so, use `median(ifelse(seg.df$email=="yes", 1, 0))` (assuming there are another other values of email, including `NA`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to take a median of character data, it simply doesn't make sense - that's not an R problem, it's a logic problem. But R can help... Maybe convert to numeric values using `ifelse()` but be what values occur in `seg.df$email` - if its only yes and no, this will work

```
median(ifelse(seg.df$email=="yes", 1, 0), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Otherwise, nested ifelse may be useful

```
median(ifelse(seg.df$email=="yes", 1, 
       ifelse(seg.df$email=="no", 0, NA)), 
       na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me